# Can we execute only failed test cases in Jenkins?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, jenkins, testng

If we build and execute selenium (TestNG) suite in Jenkins and if some tests fails; after fixing is there any way to execute only those failed test cases in Jenkins?

Comment: what have you tried? I googled this and got some articles; have you tried this one for example? https://dzone.com/articles/jenkins-testng-failed-test-cases-for-maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, from [the docs](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#rerunning):

> Every time tests fail in a suite, TestNG creates a file called testng-failed.xml in the output directory. This XML file contains the necessary information to rerun only these methods that failed, allowing you to quickly reproduce the failures without having to run the entirety of your tests.

If I understand your use case, you are looking to save the list of failed tests, make changes to the code and re-execute that list, is that correct ? In that case you can store that `testng-failed.xml` file and use it for the next execution in Jenkins, possibly adding a checkbox to the job that lets you choose wether to use this test suite or the default one.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below to run specific tests (example: testcases you have fixed) with mnetioning below include tag in testNG.xml

```
<classes>
    <class name="test.IndividualMethodsTest">
      <methods>
        <include name="testMethod" />
      </methods>
    </class>
  </classes>
```

Comment: I think OP wants to run failed tests only, which means the list will change from build to build (i.e. it's a dynamic list) - this answer will create more work and does not address the key issue because it will always run the same test (regardless of whether they failed or not)

Answer (score 0):

From my QA and automation perspective, it's always better to run the entire suite from jenkins, if you want to check why they fail you can do it locally. the other option is to parameterize the xml but it is a lot of work, it could be by maven arguments and writing in the xml

Answer (score 0):

Why in Jenkins?, you can build one Testng Retry Listener where it keeps polling the entire test execution and re-executes only Failed testcases.

Refer this below.

```
public class RetryFailedTestCases implements IRetryAnalyzer {

private int retryCnt = 0;

// Mentioned maxRetryCnt (Maximiun Retry Count) as per your requirement. Here I
// took 3, If any failed testcases then it runs two times
private int maxRetryCnt = 1;


// This method will be called everytime a test fails. It will return TRUE if a
// test fails and need to be retried, else it returns FALSE
public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {

    if (retryCnt < maxRetryCnt) {
        System.out.println("Retrying " + result.getName() + " again and the count is " + (retryCnt + 1));
        retryCnt++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
 }
```